# Can I pass array in Function.call() method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Take a look at the following code:

```js
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

console.log(new Food('cheese', 5).name);
// expected output: "cheese"
```

So, my question is can we pass an array as argument to call method just like apply method.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish (if you expect it to be "cheese", then either pass `name` or just avoid passing a array). If you just want to use .call with an array of arguments, you may want to use the ES6 spread operator: https://jsfiddle.net/94ktpamj/1/

Comment: Of course you can pass in an array, but it will come out as an array in the function arguments. If you want to pass all the arguments as an array like `apply` does it - no, that's not possible with `call`, that's what `apply` is for!

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `call` meaningfully, you can only do so if the function you're calling accepts an array as a parameter somewhere.

```js
function Product(name, price, someArr) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.arrInfo = someArr;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price, ['a', 'b', 'c']);
  this.category = 'food';
}

console.log(new Food('cheese', 5).arrInfo);
```

You can pass in a single object instead to get an effect more similar to named parameters, if that's what you're looking for:

```js
function Product({ name, price, someArr }) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.arrInfo = someArr;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, { name, price, someArr: ['a', 'b', 'c'] });
  this.category = 'food';
}

console.log(new Food('cheese', 5).arrInfo);
```

That way, you're only passing in a single variable (a reference to an object) other than `this` to `.call`.

Comment: "Only if the function you're calling accepts an array as a parameter" – That's not entirely true, being loosely typed language itself won't prevent you to pass parameter of any type.

Comment: @CertainPerformance See my updated code snippet. It seems you are wrong

Comment: @ShrirangKadale Your output is not what you're expecting though - you're sending `Product` an array, resulting in `name` being ['cheese'], which is not the same thing as the expected 'cheese'.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I got your point. Before this, I didn't know the other methods apply() and bind().